# Вызов bash скрипта из соседнего скрипта

Tags: bash, unix

В одном каталоге находятся два `bash` скрипта:

- **`a.sh`**

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  echo "Hello, world"
  ```
- **`b.sh`**

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  . a.sh
  ```

При запуске `b.sh` выскакивает ошибка:

```
user@comp: source b.sh 
b.sh:2: command not found: a.sh
```

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat b.sh
#!/bin/bash
. a.sh
```

поиск файла `a.sh` *в данном случае* будет осуществляться в *текущем* каталоге.

скорее всего, вы выполняете команду `source ...b.sh` не в том каталоге, где находится файл `a.sh`.

если и `b.sh` и `a.sh` находятся в одном каталоге, а вам требуется, чтобы команда `source ...b.sh` выполнялась успешно вне зависимости от того, какой у вашей оболочки текущий каталог, то внутри `b.sh` можно извлечь путь к нему и подставить при обращении к `a.sh`. например, так:

```
$ cat b.sh
#!/bin/bash
d=$(dirname $0)
. ${d}/a.sh
```

---

для справки: точка в команде `. a.sh` — это синоним внутренней команды оболочки `source`.

Comment: запускал из того же каталога, что и мои тестовые скрипты.

Comment: @MichaelPak, приложите, пожалуйста, к вопросу вывод команд `ps` и `/bin/bash --version`. заодно посмотрите, на какой файловой системе находятся файлы: `df b.sh` и с какими опциями эта ф.с. примонтирована: `mount | grep /путь/к/файловой/системе`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, но b.sh у него ведь запускается, а значит о `noexec` тут говорить не приходится. Мне кажется, что там банально где-то русская буква попалась. Разве что еще `which bash` посмотреть.

Comment: @andy.37, неизвестно, что за оболочку использует автор вопроса, и как она реагирует на команды `.` и `source`. потому я и запросил всю пришедшую в голову информацию.

Answer (score 1):

В Unix системах шелл при выполнении команд ищет их *исключительно* в каталогах, указанных в переменной окружения `PATH`. В текущем каталоге, в отличие от Windows, поиск не происходит.

Если текущий каталог не указан в `PATH` то скрипты из него необходимо вызывать с указанием на текущий каталог. В вашем случае полная команда вызова будет `. ./a.sh`

Comment: Теперь пишет: `b.sh:2: command not found: ./a.sh`

Comment: Что легко проверить набрав `echo $PATH`. Точки там не будет, хотя можно и добавить)

Comment: Вот, теперь 3 похожих ответа, правда у arexander barakin более правильный. Осталось понять почему у ТС это не работает :)

Answer (score 1):

a.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo hello
```

b.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
./a.sh
```

Запускаем:

```
$ chmod +x a.sh b.sh
$ ./b.sh
hello
$
```

Варианты:

1) a.sh - не исполняемый.

2) запускаете b.sh как some/path/b.sh

3) оба файла не исполняемые запускаете `bash b.sh`. В нем соотв. надо писать не `./a.sh` а `bash a.sh`. Впрочем для Вашего изначального варианта с `. a.sh` исполняемость файла не нужна.

4) где-то в одном из мест стоит русская буква "а".