# как получить путь скрипта в bash скрипте?

Tags: bash, path, sh

есть *скрипт* 
**one.sh**

```
ls -la
```

я его запускаю и получаю путь

```
~$/home/user1/: sh /home/user2/one.sh


/home/user1
```

а скрипт лежит в /home/user2

как вывести в терминал */home/user2* притом что путь *скрипта* мжет быть разный, что писать в *скрипте* ?

Comment: Если ваш скрипт содержит `ls -la`, то он не может печатать: `/home/user1`, в данном случае. Или я не правильно понял вопрос?

Comment: схожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/471300/178576

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сначала получить путь к скрипту, а потом извлечь из него путь к каталогу:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

MYPATH=$(dirname $0)

echo $MYPATH

cd $MYPATH
ls -la
```

При вызове:
`cd /home/user1 && sh /home/user2/one.sh`

Будет выведено:

> /home/user2
>
> Список файлов в `/home/user2`

Comment: Не всё так просто, когда пути относительные.